# matlab code for defining function 'int' for input arguments type 'double'

Tags: matlab

I have typed this in MATLAB:

```
clc
clear all
close all
u=1e-15:0.001:1;
for u=0.00000000001:0.001:1;
    w=int(exp(-u)/u,u,Inf);
end
figure;
plot(u,w)
grid on;
title('plot of W(u), u less 1');
ylabel('W(u)');
xlabel('different values of u');`
```

During this....I got the error

```
Undefined function or method 'int' for input arguments of type 'double'
```

Can anyone help me..?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `int` method in MatLab. Perhaps what you want is `int32`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the  [matlab help on integers](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html).

If you just want to round the result you can use `ceil`, `floor`, `round` or `fix`, which results in a floating point variable that just happens to have no fractional part, but you will get rounding errors for really big numbers. What really big means is in the [help on floating point numbers](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html).

If you want to just use an integral datatype, specify the correct one like `int32`, `uint8` etc., with all the impliciations of maximum and minimum value.